# Outlook html and css, won't show correct result in mail, but will in browser

Tags: css, outlook, html-table, html-email

I'm making a newsletter setup with `HTML` and `CSS`.

I'm using Outlook 2010.

The thing is, I've make this in Notepad++ and viewed it in firefox for debug. When everything seems ok and worked in FF, I tested it from the newsletter system.

I uploaded the `HTML`, `CSS` and pictures and everything works as it should.

Besides that I have a problem with some specific classes in the `CSS`.

I have a class called `.text10` to make the text `size 10`(for testing i make the color red to see the visual difference). The thing is, that the `TD` I've set with the class `.text10` is not getting `size 10`, but get the default `size 14` from the `body tag`, and is not getting red.

My newsletter's `header` is getting red from another class I've made.

When I open the mail and then open the source I can see that the `HTML` indeed got the class `.text10`, but its empty with no value?

What am I doing wrong, or is there something I've overseen in my `HTML` or `CSS`?
Here's a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chdy2avt/2/).

Comment: Emails and css don't mix well. My advice is to use inline styles everywhere. Here is a nice [compatibility chart](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). Or sign up for a free trial with a service like mailchimp or campaignmonitor and use their editor to create an email and look at the generated source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out you can only use one class for each element.

Example: *Will only use the class `link`, and overlook `color`*

```
<a href="www.site.com" class="link color">link</a>
```

Example: *Will work normal*

```
<a href="www.site.com" class="color">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When it is to an email template, I would advise you to make everything inline style and the things that need to be different on the phone must be in header `@media`, with a `!important` on. as shown in the example.

You can also run your test through [Litmus](https://litmus.com)

Hope it helps

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>

<style>
 @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    .paragraphText p {
        font-size: 24px !important;
    }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>                            
    <div class="paragraphText">    
        <p style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Some Text</p>
    </div>                                       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The css is working fine otherwise beside this TD. Everything else is getting the right size and colors. But this class is just empty.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup. You can find the supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties described in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the input, although i have already look at them, and I'm not using any css that's not allowed